Why i get "Maximum update" error when trying to filter data?
I'm trying to filter data from api. In fact it's working but i see error:
"FilterCheckboxGroup.js:54 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render. Error Component Stack"
valueInput is controling by input with onChange handler
const [valueInput, setValueInput] = useState('')
const [filteredDataList, setFilteredDataList] = useState([])
const [checkedFilterValues, setCheckedFilterValues] = useState()

const { isLoading, error, data } = useGetTableDataQuery(
    `${url}?${column.id}=${value ?? ''}`,
    {
        selectFromResult: ({ data, ...rest }) => {
            if (!data || !data.data) {
                return { data: [], ...rest }
            }
            const modifiedData =
                data.data.map(item => item[column.id]) || []
            const removedDuplicatesData = [...new Set(modifiedData)]
            return { data: removedDuplicatesData, ...rest }
        },
    }
)

useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.length > 0 && !isLoading) {
        if (valueInput) {
            const updatedDataList = data.filter(listItem =>
                listItem.toLowerCase().includes(valueInput.toLowerCase())
            )
            setFilteredDataList(updatedDataList)
        } else {
            setFilteredDataList(data)
        }
    }
}, [valueInput, data])


What you tried in terms of debugging? Is the reference of data that is returned from useGetTableDataQuery persistent between rerenders?

Yes, it's persistent, cause it's hook from rtk query. Not quite sure what i'm supposed to debugging

Can't explained to myself, but i think it's problem at selectFromResult in RTK, i've decided to recieved pure data and independently parse data to options state and it's worked
//API
const { isLoading, error, data } = useGetTableDataQuery(
    `${url}?${column.id}=${value ?? ''}`
    // {
    //     selectFromResult: ({ data, ...rest }) => {
    //         if (!data || !data.data) {
    //             return { data: [], ...rest }
    //         }
    //         const modifiedData =
    //             data.data.map(item => item[column.id]) || []
    //         const removedDuplicatesData = [...new Set(modifiedData)]
    //         return { data: removedDuplicatesData, ...rest }
    //     },
    // }
)

const [valueInput, setValueInput] = useState('')
const [checkedFilterValues, setCheckedFilterValues] = useState()
const [options, setOptions] = useState()
const [filteredDataList, setFilteredDataList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.data) {
        const modifiedData = data?.data.map(item => item[column.id]) || []
        const removedDuplicatesData = [...new Set(modifiedData)]
        setOptions(removedDuplicatesData)
    }
}, [data])

useEffect(() => {
    if (options) {
        if (valueInput !== '') {
            const updatedDataList = options.filter(listItem =>
                listItem.toLowerCase().includes(valueInput.toLowerCase())
            )
            setFilteredDataList(updatedDataList)
        } else {
            setFilteredDataList(options)
        }
    }
}, [valueInput, options])


Can you please see add a console.log('working') in the useEffect having data as its dependency. It seems to be it may not be working now. Sorry if am wrong.
